# What is the purpose of setting a hidden type of input tag?

Tags: css, forms

Full code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="get">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    </div>

    <label for="first">First name:</label>
    <input id="first" name="first" type="text" value="Steve" /><br/>
    <label for="last">Last name:</label>
    <input id="last" name="last" type="text" value="Jobs" /><br/>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
</div>
```

I'm reading the code from another people. I don't understand why he made a fake input field here. Is it for the css purpose?

Comment: Hidden inputs typically contain data that the form's creator wants to pass to the processing script but doesn't want to render it on the page for the viewer. It's not a "fake" input and rarely has anything to do with CSS.

Comment: @j08691 can you be specific what is the common use of hidden input

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields are used programatically, to pass information about the current page to the server.
Hidden fields can also be used to pass information back to scripts. This may include security tokens, or the name of the relevant row in the database. The user does not need to see this data, but it is passed back to the server on submission so that scripts function correctly behind the scenes.